# "Non-analytic interaction"...what does it mean?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, ergodicity

Reading [an article about Hamiltonian chaos](https://fas.org/sgp/othergov/doe/lanl/pubs/00285947.pdf), I found this passage:

> Importantly, the few Hamiltonian systems for which the KAM theorem
> does not apply, and for which one can prove ergodicity and the
> approach to thermal equilibrium, involve “hard spheres” and
> consequently contain non-analytic interactions that are not realistic
> from a physicist’s perspective.

What does the expression *non-analytic interactions* mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analytic function is one that has a power series expansion that actually converges to the function in the region of interest.  A non analytic interaction is one in which the interparticle potential $V(x-x')$ does not have this property.  For example $V(r-r')= 1/|r-r'|$ is analytic in any region in which $|r-r'|>a$ for some positive number $a$ (i.e the particles do not collide). A potential such that $V(r-r')=0$ for $|r-r'|>a$ and infinity for $|r-r'|\le a$ (hard sphere) is non-analytic.